# Android Studio by default opens iPhone XR simulator. How to change it?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, flutter, dart

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Whenever I tap on this option it always opens up iPhone XR simulator, is there any way to change it? Like open iPhone 8 plus.

---

**Note:**

I know that I can open other simulators from Xcode by first running the app there, stopping the ongoing process, opening Android Studio and start running the app again from it. That's too much work, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, run the app, it would launch iPhone XR, then click on the emulator in the dock menu. After that check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eycaj.jpg).

Now select your preferred simulator, it will launch alongside another simulator which is already running, now close all the simulators, next time you open simulator, it shall open iPhone 8.